# IOS: SECURITY WARNING: The above URL is not valid for a cash card or gift card

Tags: facebook, facebook-oauth

My IOS app uses a facebook login button. When you click on the button, it brings up the Facebook login prompt.  After entering your information, it brings up a white screen that says:

> **SECURITY WARNING:** The above URL is **NOT NOT VALID FOR A CASH CARD OR GIFT CARD**. Giving away the URL **may result in your account being HIJACKED**.

I can't seem to find anything online about this problem.  Any ideas where I should start looking?

We're using the client side flow as recommended by facebook for Desktop applications. Read more [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/#client-side-flow)

The page that contains this message is found at http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html

Comment: Which Facebook API you are using

Comment: Looks like whatever API you are using it is hitting this page or another page... http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html Few other people have mentioned it in the past 24 hours if you google the message. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12271457#post12271457

Comment: saw the same error message on our Desktop Application.

Comment: My developer said the problem was fixed when using facebook connect.