# Facebook Issues Success

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IOS: SECURITY WARNING: The above URL is not valid for a cash card or gift card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674417/ios-security-warning-the-above-url-is-not-valid-for-a-cash-card-or-gift-card)

I am Facing this issues from today only. Please help me because I want to upload IPA today and its started just now. Till today It was working fine.

**SECURITY WARNING:** The above URL is **NOT NOT VALID FOR A CASH CARD OR GIFT CARD**. Giving away the URL **may result in your account being HIJACKED**.

And My Facebook functionality stopped without changing any code.

[image]

Comment: you need to be way more specific

Comment: @LuisOscar till today when Facebook login is succeeded It retuned just "success" and I am parsing that html data and proceed ahead but from today its not working without changing any code. It shows me above warning which is in above picture.